# Keyboard on appeon mobile app

Tags: powerbuilder

I started using Powerbuilder with Appeon mobile recently.
I noticed that I need to click twice on a datawindow field to show keyboard on iOS/Android.
There is no problem when I click on a single line edit field outside datawindow - keyboard shows after first click.

How can I enable single click on datawindow fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try Appeon Mobile 2016. With this version you can invoke keyboard by long pressing input area (such as, long pressing on a DataWindow field).